# How do i modify this LPSTR?

Tags: c, winapi, api

Let's suppose for a moment i have this variable

```
LPTSTR cmdArgs = "D:\\path\my.exe -user blah PLATFORM=0 DEVICE=0 -k poclbm VECTORS BFI_INT WORKSIZE=128 AGGRESSION=7";
```

Notice where it says *DEVICE=0* well, in my case it could be DEVICE=1 or DEVICE=2 etc.

That would mean that, that string must be dynamic. I am going to pass to a function the number which would should come after DEVICE= however, i have no idea how to add it to the cmdArgs variable.

I was thinking of using sprintf and do DEVICE=%d, but i've no idea if i can cast a char variable(which will contain the formatted string) to an LPSTR

Comment: Is it LPTSTR as in your code line or LPSTR as in your question?

Comment: If you want to keep using this feature from the previous century then be consistent.  Use LPTSTR, TCHAR buffer[], _T("literal") and _stprintf().  There is not much point left, the floppy disk drive on the last running non-Unicode version of Windows died last week.

Answer (score 2):

An `LPSTR` is a typedef for a `char *`. You can use `sprintf` for inserting the device number into the string.

```
char cmdArgs[1000];
int deviceNum = 1;
sprintf( cmdArgs, "D:\\path\\my.exe -user blah PLATFORM=0 DEVICE=%d -k poclbm VECTORS BFI_INT WORKSIZE=128 AGGRESSION=7", deviceNum );
```

**EDIT:**
Since the code snippet shows an `LPTSTR` you may want to use TCHAR routines instead of `sprintf`. `LPTSTR` is typedef'd as `whcar_t *` when `_UNICODE` preprocessor symbol is defined, and `char *` if that symbol is not defined or `_MBCS` is defined.

```
TCHAR cmdArgs[1000];
int deviceNum = 1;
_stprintf( cmdArgs, _T(""D:\\path\\my.exe -user blah PLATFORM=0 DEVICE=%d -k poclbm VECTORS BFI_INT WORKSIZE=128 AGGRESSION=7"), deviceNum );
```

Comment: He said `LPTSTR`, so you want `_tsprintf`.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks, you're right. The title of the question says LPSTR, but the code snippet itself says LPTSTR

Answer (score 1):

Your summary says LPSTR, but your code block says LPTSTR.  These (might) be different things, depending on if you're building for Unicode or not.

In unicode builds, LPTSTR is a wchar_t*.  In non-unicode, LPTSTR is char*.  LPSTR is char* in both cases.

winnt.h has these typedefs (these aren't the literal typedef's, I've kinda paraphrased them here):

```
typedef char CHAR;
typedef CHAR *LPSTR;

typedef wchar_t WCHAR;
typedef WCHAR *LPWSTR;

#ifdef UNICODE
typedef LPWSTR LPTSTR;
#else
typedef LPSTR LPTSTR;
#endif
```

If you're building non-Unicode, sprintf with %d will do what you want, as specified by others here.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use %s, since you have a `char *`.

Comment: Right, i guess i had a brain fart there :). Anywho, i still dont know if a char* can be casted to an LPSTR.